# I'm looking for a script, utility or command to batch rename files of a particular naming scheme

Tags: linux, windows, macos, batch-rename

A sample of the files I need to rename:

```
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-bs-latn-ba-package_100e5dc9f1eb0cc3f9ef59c60dd24543827a6c48.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-bn-in-package_679f41a31fa39e91da733edba47cc8e3cd8013d4.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-bn-bd-package_81a64b49f357d8eef17d8797ddba200c04c9805e.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-bg-bg-package_59a6ca257ed175d72efc6718f153837fb48d1890.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-az-latn-az-package_943c512fe9e0917c6116d4f81a764f0144d8a67f.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-as-in-package_e8363efa6389494eedc61f26057ab333d8c11a55.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-ar-sa-package_fc97e593423319e11b7521f8076a5de21348e831.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-af-za-package_b498b23dfb0271d34850f331fdaeffacf3d97ed5.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-de-de-package_34de150bd496f5e06b7c9eee2227650c54b11a27.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-da-dk-package_31a2dd00b08c9d7cdaba85c5c60777eaa75166bf.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-cy-gb-package_065ebd6f0adcc91feb98e943b4599cc6b656ed05.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-cs-cz-package_2eac7ee66be70c97d357ca70101e0c93af2387f1.cab
microsoft-windows-languagefeatures-basic-ca-es-package_437de767fb26329de81b3a92cd95e970a6d1e451.cab
```

I only want to keep the "basic-langcode" part, but I don't know how to batch rename files to achieve that result.

Also I'm looking to do this via a method that works on Windows, Linux and MacOS, but that's a bonus requirement.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the 'Bulk Rename Utility'? I have used if for renaming multiple files and found it very useful and flexible. It takes a little getting used to but it comes with great instructions and is reasonably easy to use. Give it a try!
It can be found here - 
[http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)

Oh! and by the way .... it's free!

Comment: +1 For Windows, Bulk Rename Utility is a really great program. Relatively easy to use and powerful, depending on needs.

Comment: I've used this too for many years. BRU is a winner.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the [rename package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/rename) (it used to be in the [Perl package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/perl)) has a script/utility called `prename` ([in Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275254/why-is-the-rename-utility-on-debian-ubuntu-different-than-the-one-on-other-distr) it's the command `rename`), and being a perl script you should be able to run it on anything. It can do this:

```
NAME
   rename - renames multiple files

SYNOPSIS
   rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]

DESCRIPTION
   "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as
   the first argument.  The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression which is
   expected to modify the $_ string in Perl for at least some of the filenames
   specified.  If a given filename is not modified by the expression, it will
   not be renamed.  If no filenames are given on the command line, filenames
   will be read via standard input.

   For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the extension,
   you might say

           rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak

   To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use

           rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

The easy way is to find something specific about the filenames you want to "erase," maybe running it twice to erase the leading & trailing stuff. The hard way is to find a perlexpr match like maybe a dash then two lowercase letters characters then a dash, followed optionally by stuff, then another dash two lowercase letters characters dash and have it rename to just the match.